# Which type is required in mongodb-node find method in typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongodb

```
async function findUsers(find_pattern: Filter<Document>, sort?: Sort): Promise<Array<any>> {
  return await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    dbClient.db('main').collection('accounts').find(find_pattern).sort((sort ?? { joindate: -1 })).toArray()
      .then((result: Array<any>) => {
        resolve(result);
      })
      .catch((err: any) => {
        reject(err);
      })
  })
}
```

And the error occurred:
The error seems to be in the type required for `find()` method
Thanks

```
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 3, '(filter: Filter<Document>, options?: FindOptions<Document> | undefined): FindCursor<WithId<Document>>', gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'import("/Users/siang/+coding/joinstu-ts/backend/node_modules/mongodb/mongodb").Filter<Document>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'import("/Users/siang/+coding/joinstu-ts/backend/node_modules/mongodb/mongodb").Filter<import("/Users/siang/+coding/joinstu-ts/backend/node_modules/bson/bson").Document>'.
      Type 'Filter<Document>' is not assignable to type 'RootFilterOperators<WithId<Document>>'.
        Types of property '$and' are incompatible.
          Type 'import("/Users/siang/+coding/joinstu-ts/backend/node_modules/mongodb/mongodb").Filter<import("/Users/siang/+coding/joinstu-ts/backend/node_modules/mongodb/mongodb").WithId<Document>>[] | undefined' is not assignable to type 'import("/Users/siang/+coding/joinstu-ts/backend/node_modules/mongodb/mongodb").Filter<import("/Users/siang/+coding/joinstu-ts/backend/node_modules/mongodb/mongodb").WithId<import("/Users/siang/+coding/joinstu-ts/backend/node_modules/bson/bson").Document>>[] | undefined'.
            Type 'import("/Users/siang/+coding/joinstu-ts/backend/node_modules/mongodb/mongodb").Filter<import("/Users/siang/+coding/joinstu-ts/backend/node_modules/mongodb/mongodb").WithId<Document>>[]' is not assignable to type 'import("/Users/siang/+coding/joinstu-ts/backend/node_modules/mongodb/mongodb").Filter<import("/Users/siang/+coding/joinstu-ts/backend/node_modules/mongodb/mongodb").WithId<import("/Users/siang/+coding/joinstu-ts/backend/node_modules/bson/bson").Document>>[]'.
              Type 'import("/Users/siang/+coding/joinstu-ts/backend/node_modules/mongodb/mongodb").Filter<import("/Users/siang/+coding/joinstu-ts/backend/node_modules/mongodb/mongodb").WithId<Document>>' is not assignable to type 'import("/Users/siang/+coding/joinstu-ts/backend/node_modules/mongodb/mongodb").Filter<import("/Users/siang/+coding/joinstu-ts/backend/node_modules/mongodb/mongodb").WithId<import("/Users/siang/+coding/joinstu-ts/backend/node_modules/bson/bson").Document>>'.
                Type 'Filter<WithId<Document>>' is not assignable to type 'RootFilterOperators<WithId<WithId<Document>>>'.
                  Types of property '$where' are incompatible.
                    Type 'string | ((this: import("/Users/siang/+coding/joinstu-ts/backend/node_modules/mongodb/mongodb").WithId<import("/Users/siang/+coding/joinstu-ts/backend/node_modules/mongodb/mongodb").WithId<Document>>) => boolean) | undefined' is not assignable to type 'string | ((this: import("/Users/siang/+coding/joinstu-ts/backend/node_modules/mongodb/mongodb").WithId<import("/Users/siang/+coding/joinstu-ts/backend/node_modules/mongodb/mongodb").WithId<import("/Users/siang/+coding/joinstu-ts/backend/node_modules/bson/bson").Document>>) => boolean) | undefined'.
                      Type '(this: WithId<WithId<Document>>) => boolean' is not assignable to type 'string | ((this: WithId<WithId<Document>>) => boolean) | undefined'.
                        Type '(this: import("/Users/siang/+coding/joinstu-ts/backend/node_modules/mongodb/mongodb").WithId<import("/Users/siang/+coding/joinstu-ts/backend/node_modules/mongodb/mongodb").WithId<Document>>) => boolean' is not assignable to type '(this: import("/Users/siang/+coding/joinstu-ts/backend/node_modules/mongodb/mongodb").WithId<import("/Users/siang/+coding/joinstu-ts/backend/node_modules/mongodb/mongodb").WithId<import("/Users/siang/+coding/joinstu-ts/backend/node_modules/bson/bson").Document>>) => boolean'.
                          The 'this' types of each signature are incompatible.
                            Type 'import("/Users/siang/+coding/joinstu-ts/backend/node_modules/mongodb/mongodb").WithId<import("/Users/siang/+coding/joinstu-ts/backend/node_modules/mongodb/mongodb").WithId<import("/Users/siang/+coding/joinstu-ts/backend/node_modules/bson/bson").Document>>' is not assignable to type 'import("/Users/siang/+coding/joinstu-ts/backend/node_modules/mongodb/mongodb").WithId<import("/Users/siang/+coding/joinstu-ts/backend/node_modules/mongodb/mongodb").WithId<Document>>'.
                              Type 'WithId<WithId<Document>>' is missing the following properties from type 'Pick<WithId<Document>, keyof Document>': URL, alinkColor, all, anchors, and 250 more.
  Overload 2 of 3, '(filter: Filter<Document>, options?: FindOptions<Document> | undefined): FindCursor<Document>', gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'import("/Users/siang/+coding/joinstu-ts/backend/node_modules/mongodb/mongodb").Filter<Document>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'import("/Users/siang/+coding/joinstu-ts/backend/node_modules/mongodb/mongodb").Filter<import("/Users/siang/+coding/joinstu-ts/backend/node_modules/bson/bson").Document>'.`
```

Which type is required in mongodb-node `find` method in typescript

Comment: Can't reproduce using `mongodb: 5.6.0`